# How to enter safe-mode from command-line in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8, command-line, boot, safe-mode

I would like to enter safe-mode in the next booting but only using command-line.

By using GUI, what I typically do is to run msconfig and choose safe-boot option in the menu.

Without this GUI button-clicking, I would like to just write the command and boot into safe-mode in the next boot. Is there a way for doing this?

PS. I tried

```
bcdedit /set {default} bootmenupolicy legacy
```

but it does not work in Windows 8.1

Comment: You mean, like "reboot" in Linux? IMHO this is in Windows 8.1 not possible :(

Answer (score 2):

This will build the safe mode entries.

```
bcdedit /set "{default}" bootmenupolicy legacy
bcdedit /set "{default}" safeboot minimal
bcdedit /copy "{default}" /d "Windows Safe Mode"
bcdedit /set "{default}" safeboot network
bcdedit /copy "{default}" /d "Windows Safe Mode with Networking"
bcdedit /set "{default}" safebootalternateshell yes
bcdedit /copy "{default}" /d "Windows Safe Mode with Command Prompt"
bcdedit /deletevalue "{default}" safebootalternateshell
bcdedit /deletevalue "{default}" safeboot
bcdedit /timeout 5
```

Here is the result.

[image]

For more info.

http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/50059-How-to-enter-the-Safe-Mode-in-Windows8-1

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a fully command line way to do it, however doing `shutdown /r /o` will get you to the menu where you can choose to reboot to safemode from the command line.